# How to travese two dictionaries in a single for loop?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to generate the following effect :

```
for i, j in d.items() and k, v in c.items():
    print i, j, k, v
```

This is wrong. I want to know how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
for (i, j), (k, v) in zip(d.items(), c.items()):
   print i, j, k, v
```

Remember the order will be arbitrary unless your dictionaries are `OrderedDict`s. To be memory efficient

In Python 2.x (where `dict.items` and `zip` create lists) you can do the following:

```
from itertools import izip
for (i, j), (k, v) in izip(d.iteritems(), c.iteritems()):
   print i, j, k, v
```

This won't necessarily be faster, as you will observe on small lists it's faster to iterate over these intermediate lists however you will notice a speed improvement when iterating very large data structures.

In Python 3.x `zip` is the same as `izip` (which no longer exists) and `dict.items` (`dict.iteritems` no longer exists) returns a [*view*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957750/what-are-python-dictionary-view-objects) instead of a *list*.

Answer (score 2):

You question doesn't make it clear, whether you want to iterate the dictionaries in two nested for-loops, or side by side (as done in @jamylak's answer)

Here is the nested interpretation

```
from itertools import product
for (i, j), (k, v) in product(d.items(), c.items()):
    print i, j, k, v
```

eg

```
>>> d={'a':'Apple', 'b':'Ball'}
>>> c={'1':'One', '2':'Two'}
>>> from itertools import product
>>> for (i, j), (k, v) in product(d.items(), c.items()):
...     print i, j, k, v
... 
a Apple 1 One
a Apple 2 Two
b Ball 1 One
b Ball 2 Two
```

Comment: Probably worth mentioning *how* the question was unclear - in particular, `product` gives a similar result to iterating the dictionaries in two *nested* for-loops, while jamylak's answer using `zip` gives a similar result to two *adjacent* for-loops.