# Subclassing datatypes that have views in Python2.7 and Python3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Python 3 introduced views (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8960727/1326104)). They were also backported to Python 2.7. I am currently in the process of subclassing `dict` in a Python 2.7 application (though with the goal to port it to Python 3 as well). I was wondering if - and how - I could subclass the `.viewitems()` and similar functions in such a way that they behave exactly like the original views.

Here is my intent: I have a dictonary like this:

```
data = my_subclassed_dict
data["_internal"] = "internal_value"
data["key"] = "value"
list(data.keys()) == ["key"]
```

That is, I filter everything stat starts with a `"_"`. This works fine so far: For iterators I just `yield` and for lists I use a list comprehension that filters undesired values. However, those items have no connection the `dict` anymore (which is fine, it feels exactly like a dict). However, with both ways, this does not work:

```
keys = data.viewkeys()
"key" in keys
del data["key"]
"key" not in keys # This is False !
```

The last part does not work because there is no reference to the original keys, so Python won't notice.

So: Is there a **simple** way to achieve this (without re-implementing all of the logic!)?

This is more of a question out of interest as I don't see it to apply that much in my scenario.

Comment: The C code for the view objects has the following TODO comment: *support arbitrary mappings?*...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `view` objects basically 'empty' proxies. They point to the original dictionary.

Unfortunately, the current dictionary view objects are not really reusable. Quoting from the [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a9f7c2d49149/Objects/dictobject.c#l2813):

> ```
> /* TODO(guido): The views objects are not complete:
>
>  * support more set operations
>  * support arbitrary mappings?
>    - either these should be static or exported in dictobject.h
>    - if public then they should probably be in builtins
> */
> ```

Note the `support arbitrary mappings` entry; these objects do *not* support arbitrary mappings, nor can we create new instances or subclass these from Python code:

```
>>> type({}.viewkeys())({})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot create 'dict_keys' instances
>>> class MyView(type({}.viewkeys())): pass
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    type 'dict_keys' is not an acceptable base type
```

You are forced to create your own and implement all the hooks the view objects support:

```
class DictKeys(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.parent)

    def __contains__(self, key):
        return key in self.parent

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.parent)
```

etc.

The methods the original objects implement are:

```
>>> dir({}.viewkeys())
['__and__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__or__', '__rand__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__ror__', '__rsub__', '__rxor__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__sub__', '__subclasshook__', '__xor__']
```

The `__and__`, `__or__`, `__sub__`, `__xor__`, `__rand__`, `__ror__`, `__rsub__` and `__rxor__` methods implement overrides for the `&`, `|` and `^` operators to provide set operations.

If you are reasonably secure in reading C code, take a look at the [view objects implementation](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a9f7c2d49149/Objects/dictobject.c#l2754) to peek at how they implement their methods.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It seems I just won't support this interface/behavior then. The dictionary isn't big anyway.

Comment: Would love to see you revisit this answer / post a second answer that takes into account where things are now language-implementation-wise...

Answer (score 0):

Consider storing any key that starts with an underscore in a separate dict. You won't have to implement `keys`, `iterkeys`, `viewitems`, etc, but you may need to reimplement a lot of other methods.