# Is dict_keys a generator function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, generator

```
>>> d = {'m': 'mango', 'f': 'fish', 'a': 'apple'}
>>> d
{'m': 'mango', 'f': 'fish', 'a': 'apple'}
>>> d.keys()
dict_keys(['m', 'f', 'a'])
>>> for x in d.keys(): print(x)
m
f
a
>>> |
```

What is `dict_keys()` and how to override this in a method (the way `__iter__`
is overridden)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dict_keys()` is a [dictionary view object](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects); such objects are [*iterables*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable) (meaning you can create multiple independent [*iterators*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator) for such an object, using [`iter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter)).

You can return your own implementation of such an object from a `.keys()` method. The specific type returned by `dict.keys()` is not available for re-use, you'll have to implement your own from scratch.

I covered creating your own in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17750065); there are a fair number of methods to cover.

Note that [generator functions](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator) are merely a *technique to create an iterator* using a Python function. All generator functions produce an iterator when called, but not all iterators are generator iterators. You can also create iterators with a generator *expression*, or by including an [`__iter__` method that returns `self`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__iter__) and a [`__next__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__next__) that produces one of the items each time it is called.