# python class with views

Tags: python, class, data-structures, view

so many data structures and classes have functions that return a "view" of the class. What this means is that it is not independent: **it changes when the class instance does even after it has been declared**

## example:

```
>>> d
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
>>> keys = d.keys()
>>> kview = d.viewkeys()
>>> keys
['a', 'c', 'b']
>>> kview
dict_keys(['a', 'c', 'b'])
>>> d['d'] = 4
>>> keys
['a', 'c', 'b']
>>> kview
dict_keys(['a', 'c', 'b', 'd'])
```

so as you can see, a class `dict_keys` is created that is considered a "view" of the keys in the dictionary data structure because it updates as the data structure updates.

**How can you make views to classes?**

## note:

this is not a question on dictionaries, this is a question on how to create "views" for any type of class. numpy arrays have an attribute `t`, which is simply a view on the same array, just transposed.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957750/what-are-python-dictionary-view-objects

Comment: yes, but that doesn't give me information I don't know. That says what they are, not how to create them for your own given class

Comment: Custom implement the `__str__` method?

Comment: this is not how it is printed, it's called a view

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3106/#specification

> The view objects are not directly mutable, but don't implement
>   **hash**(); their value can change if the underlying dict is mutated.
>
> The only requirements on the underlying dict are that it implements
>   **getitem**(), **contains**(), **iter**(), and **len**().

You can see a sample implementation there

Comment: yes but this is a more general question, not just how to do it for a dictionary-like class. +1 because I kind of get the idea, but I can't see a good general application