# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict_keys' and 'list'

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror, bidi

I am trying to use a Python package called bidi.
In a module in this package (algorithm.py) there are some lines that give me error, although it is part of the package.

Here are the lines:

```
_LEAST_GREATER_ODD = lambda x: (x + 1) | 1
_LEAST_GREATER_EVEN = lambda x: (x + 2) & ~1

X2_X5_MAPPINGS = {
    'RLE': (_LEAST_GREATER_ODD, 'N'),
    'LRE': (_LEAST_GREATER_EVEN, 'N'),
    'RLO': (_LEAST_GREATER_ODD, 'R'),
    'LRO': (_LEAST_GREATER_EVEN, 'L'),
}

# Added 'B' so X6 won't execute in that case and X8 will run its course
X6_IGNORED = X2_X5_MAPPINGS.keys() + ['BN', 'PDF', 'B']
X9_REMOVED = X2_X5_MAPPINGS.keys() + ['BN', 'PDF']
```

If I run the code in Python 3 I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    from bidi.algorithm import get_display
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\python_bidi-0.3.4-py3.3.egg\bidi\algorithm.py", line 41, in <module>
    X6_IGNORED = X2_X5_MAPPINGS.keys() + ['BN', 'PDF', 'B']
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict_keys' and 'list'
```

Why there is this error although this is part of the bidi package? Does it have anything to do with my Python version? I appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In Python 3.x, `dict.keys` returns a [dictionary view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957750/what-are-python-dictionary-view-objects):

```
>>> a = {1:1, 2:2}
>>> a.keys()
dict_keys([1, 2])
>>> type(a.keys())
<class 'dict_keys'>
>>>
```

You can get what you want by putting those views in [`list`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#list):

```
X6_IGNORED = list(X2_X5_MAPPINGS.keys()) + ['BN', 'PDF', 'B']
X9_REMOVED = list(X2_X5_MAPPINGS.keys()) + ['BN', 'PDF']
```

Actually, you don't even need `.keys` anymore since iterating over a dictionary yields its keys:

```
X6_IGNORED = list(X2_X5_MAPPINGS) + ['BN', 'PDF', 'B']
X9_REMOVED = list(X2_X5_MAPPINGS) + ['BN', 'PDF']
```

Comment: in docs it is called [`dictionary view`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#id3)

Comment: @alko - True.  I adjusted my post and added a sweet link I found explaining views in detail.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it has something to do with your Python version. In Python 2.x, `dict.keys` returns a list of a dictionary’s keys. In Python 3.x, it provides a [view object](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views) of the keys.

You can call `list()` on the result to make it a list, [or just call `list()` on the entire dictionary as a shortcut](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict).

Answer (score 3):

In Python 3.x, `dict.keys` doesn't return a list, but instead a `view` object, `dict_keys`.

To achieve what you wanted, you need to convert it to a list:

```
X6_IGNORED = list(X2_X5_MAPPINGS.keys()) + ['BN', 'PDF', 'B']
```