# TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array, using numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm using this code, straight from the scikit-learn page. It creates a dictionary:

```
symbol_dict = {
    'TOT': 'Total',
    'XOM': 'Exxon',
    'CVX': 'Chevron',}
symbols, names = np.array(symbol_dict.items()).T
```

But I get an error:

```
TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array
```

This code is straight from the example code, so I have no idea what's going wrong.

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: Your code works perfectly when I try it. The problem seems to be coming from something you haven't shown. The traceback would make debugging this much easier.

Comment: Are you on Python 3? On Python 3, `items` returns a dict view, which NumPy doesn't understand. Use `np.array(list(symbol_dict.items())).T` to turn the view into a list of tuples, which NumPy will recognize properly.

Comment: Thanks user2357112 That fixes things.

Comment: user2357112, This fixed it for me too. Why not post this as the answer?

Answer (score 2):

As user2357112 said, in Python 3 `dict.items()` returns a dictionary view object rather than a list of key-value pairs ([the difference is explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8960727)). Wrapping it in `list()` creates a list which is something NumPy can turn into an array:

```
np.array(list(symbol_dict.items()))
```