# Removing apostrophe from elements of list in Python language

Tags: python, list

I am creating a list by iteration in python and my list looks like this

```
l = ['x','y','z']
```

I want to make my list look like this without apostrophe on its elements

```
l = [x,y,z]
```

Problem with the first notation is that my viewkeys() is taking j as a string name ,not as a dictionary name.Second notation works fine.Here x,y,z are dictionary names.

```
keys=reduce(lambda i,j: i | j ,[j.viewkeys() for j in l])
```

I tried strip('\'') but failed.Any suggestions?

If I have:

```
x = {'a':1, 'b': 2, 'c':5}
y = {'b':10, 'c': 11}
z = {'e':5, 'b': 2}
l=[x,y,z]
keys=reduce(lambda i, j: i | j, [j.viewkeys() for j in l])
```

This code will run fine.But when i am trying to create l list iteratively it is taking as

```
l = ['x','y','z']
```

and the `viewkeys()` is giving error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'viewkeys'

Comment: What do you mean by "looks like"?

Comment: why do you want to remove the apostrophe? Strings in python are encased in apostrophe (actually quotes)

Comment: The first code line is a list of strings, the second is a list of variables. They aren't the same.

Comment: `x = {'a':1, 'b': 2, 'c':5}
y = {'b':10, 'c': 11}
 z = {'e':5, 'b': 2}
 l=[x,y,z]

 keys=reduce(lambda i,j: i | j ,[j.viewkeys() for j in l])`

This code will run fine.But when i am trying to create l list iteratively it is taking as  l = ['x','y','z'] and the viewkeys() is giving error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'viewkeys'`.

Comment: @Celeo How to convert first list into the second list which do not contain apostrophe.

Comment: `.viewkeys` are to be used on a dictionary. You cant use them on strings, there is no 'method' called viewkeys for strings.

Comment: When you say *"interactively*," @rombi, what are you specifically describing? Are you running code in a file or using an IDE/shell?

Comment: @celeo here x,y,z are dictionary names only

Comment: @Celeo typing into a file

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? What is the goal of your program (or this part)

Comment: to run viewkeys() method. @letsc

Comment: @rombi - `.viewkeys()` gives you all the keys in your dictionary in the form of a list. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22890201/whats-the-data-type-returned-by-dict-viewkeys-python-2-7

Comment: @letsc I know that. But the problem here is that it is taking x,y,z as a string  and not as dictionary name

Comment: If you have `x,y and z` defined then you dont need  to enclose them in strings. Python will be able to detect that they are variable names and since they are dictionaries you can perform .vewkeys on them. Look at celeo's answer

Answer (score 4):

If, as you stated, you have

```
x = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 5}
y = {'b': 10, 'c': 11}
z = {'e': 5, 'b': 2}
```

and put those dictionaries into a list

```
l = [x, y, z]
```

and then do

```
keys = reduce(lambda i, j: i | j, [j.viewkeys() for j in l])
```

you code will, as you noted, run.

The distinction that is important is that `x` is a dictionary. `'x'` is a string literal of the character x on your keyboard. They aren't interchangeable.

You get the error you posted because `viewkeys` is a method to be used on *dictionaries*, no *strings*. You can call `viewkeys` on `x` because it's a dictionary. You cannot call `viewkeys` on `'x'` because it's a string.

If you want to get the dictionary, you need to use `x`, not `'x'`.

Comment: I understand that.But how to do it 
`for key in features.keys(): 
  globals().setdefault(key,get_count(features[key]))
  dicts.append(key)`
here i am creating dictionaries and appending their names to dicts list. But they are appended as ['x','y','z'] and not as [x,y,z]. There are like 1000 dictionaries to be appended,hence i cannot do it manually.
Is there a way around to circumvent this.?

Comment: Can u help with this ?

Comment: Be sure that you're not adding the keys to your list. You want to add the *values*, as those contain the actual dictionaries.

Answer (score 3):

The string-form of a container always uses the `repr` of the container's items (otherwise ambiguities would be inevitable).

Nobody stops you from doing your own formatting, e.g:

```
def showmyway(alist):
    return '[{}]'.format(','.join(str(s) for s in alist))
```

and then for example

```
print(showmyway(somelist))
```

Of course, you'll suffer the inevitable ambiguity too: for example,

```
showmyway(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

and

```
showmyway(['a,b', 'c'])
```

will return exactly the same string, despite being very different lists.

Comment: My list belongs to the second category of 'showmyway(['a,b', 'c'])'. Is there a way to get out of it.@Alex Martelli

Comment: @rombi, how would you want to display such a two-item list vs one with three single-letter items?  Give clear, complete specs, and it's easy to code to them.  I don't think **any** spec on the vague lines of not putting quotes around strings can even be satisfactory in a broadly general way, but maybe you can fully specify a very special-case (your specs so far are vague, confusing, and contradictory, whence I guess the many downvotes, but maybe you can do better!).

Comment: Thanks for having faith in me.
 
`for key in features.keys(): globals().setdefault(key,get_count(features[key])) 
dicts.append(key)` 
here i am creating dictionaries and appending their names to dicts list. But they are appended as ['x','y','z'] and not as [x,y,z]. I want the name of dictionaries to be appended in [x,y,z] format without any apostrophe so that i can call viewkeys() method on it. See my updated question