# Reversed OrderedDict TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, reverse

I have an ordered dictionary and I am trying to go through it in reverse order, basically starting from the last (key, value) inserted.

```
dicts = OrderedDict()
...
for key, value in reversed(dicts.items()):
```

The above code works fine when I use PyCharm with Python 3.5.1, but when I place it on codefights, using their Python 3 interpreter (not sure what exact version), I get the error below for the for loop implementation:

```
TypeError: argument to reversed() must be a sequence
```

Why is this error happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: I believe `dicts.items()` must be casted to a list or even a tuple.

Answer (score 9):

As per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), `OrderedDict.items()` only supported `reversed` from 3.5, so I expect it's an older version.

One way you could fix it is convert to a list first:

```
for key, value in reversed(list(dicts.items())):
     ...
```

**NB**: as per the comments, `dicts.items()` should be memory efficient but `list(dicts.items())` will definitely create a new list with length the number of items in `dicts`. Most of the time this should be fine, but for very large `dicts` this will see a O(N) memory usage hit which may be significant.

Comment: What would be the best way to make it work on an older version ?

Comment: Is the `list` conversion less memory efficient than a `dicts.items()` call? It's not like `dicts.items()` is a generator

Comment: @Chris_Rands In python3 `dicts.items()` returns a [dictionary view object](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) that is memory efficient. `list`ing it creates a copy of the items in memory. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8960727/3901060

Comment: So, given what @FamousJameous said, it _does_ use (potentially a lot) more memory. Maybe you should "unscratch" your comment...