# How to check an object has the type 'dict_items'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, types, python-collections

In Python 3, I need to test whether my variable has the type 'dict_items', so I tried something like that :

```
>>> d={'a':1,'b':2}
>>> d.items()
dict_items([('a', 1), ('b', 2)])
>>> isinstance(d.items(),dict_items)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'dict_items' is not defined
```

But `dict_items` is not a known type. it is not defined in `types` module neither. How can I test an object has the type `dict_items` (without consuming data) ?

Comment: Related reading: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47273297/18771

Comment: There's no way to get it directly, you could either use `type({}.items())` or use `abc.ItemsView` which basically does the [same thing internally](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/_collections_abc.py#L53). Many other types under [`types` module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/types.py) are also defined in the same way.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`collections.abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.ItemsView):

```
from collections import abc

isinstance(d.items(), abc.ItemsView)  # True
```

Note `dict_items` is a *subclass* of `abc.ItemsView`, rather than the *same* class. For greater precision, you can use:

```
isinstance(d.items(), type({}.items()))
```

To clarify the above, you can use `issubclass`:

```
issubclass(type(d.items()), abc.ItemsView)  # True
issubclass(abc.ItemsView, type(d.items()))  # False
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this approach

```
d={'a':1,'b':2}
d.items()

assert type(d.items()).__name__ == 'dict_items', 'Not dict_items!!!!'
assert d.items().__class__.__name__ == 'dict_items', 'Not dict_items!!!!'
```