# dict_items class not showing correct class inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, method-resolution-order

I was going through this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52001019/how-to-check-an-object-has-the-type-dict-items) where I found that `<class 'dict_items'>` is a subclass of `<class 'collections.abc.ItemsView'>`. You can test this using:

```
>>> import collections
>>> issubclass({}.items().__class__, collections.abc.ItemsView)
True
```

However, I went a bit further and checked the `__mro__` attribute of `<class 'dict_items'>` and as this is a **subclass** of `<class 'collections.abc.ItemsView'>`, it should be printed when I print the `__mro__` attribute but it isn't there.

```
>>> {}.items().__class__.__mro__
(<class 'dict_items'>, <class 'object'>)
```

I also checked the subclasses of `<class 'collections.abc.ItemsView'>`

```
>>> collections.abc.ItemsView.__subclasses__()
[<class 'collections._OrderedDictItemsView'>]
```

Can anyone tell me why am I getting this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ItemsView` explicitly registers `DictItems` as a "virtual subclass" of it](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f014f1567c081542aaf5cecce118edf35e09bcc5/Lib/_collections_abc.py#L897), so that's what's being checked here.

Even in cases where a type isn't `register`ed explicitly though, `issubclass` can still report that one type is a subtype of another even when that isn't literally true. `issubclass` doesn't necessarily tell you if one thing is a literal subclass of another, [since that behavior can be overridden](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#id17):

> These ABCs override `object.__subclasshook__()` **to support testing an interface by verifying the required methods are present** and have not been set to None. This only works for simple interfaces. More complex interfaces require registration or direct subclassing.

Comment: Yes, the issue is that it is a virtual subclass, not that the type is defined in C (which does support single inheritance, using the `tp_base` slot: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_base)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks. I'll fix up my answer. I forgot about `tp_base`.