# Speeding up nested loop comparison

Tags: python, numpy, loops

I have two arrays `arr1` and `arr2` with sizes `(90000,1)` and `(120000,1)`. I'd like to find out if any element of `axis=0` of `arr1` is present on `arr2`. Then write their positions on to a list and later remove them. This will ensure that none of the elements on either lists could be found on the other. For now, I'm using `for` loops:

```
list_conflict=[]
for i in range (len(arr1)):
    for j in range (len(arr2)):
        if (arr1[i]==arr2[j]):
            list_conflict.append([i,j])

fault_index_pos = np.unique([x[0] for x in list_conflict])
fault_index_neg = np.unique([x[1] for x in list_conflict])

X_neg = np.delete(X_neg,fault_index_neg,axis=0)
X_pos = np.delete(X_pos,fault_index_pos,axis=0)
```

It takes an element of `arr1` on outer loop and compares it with every element of `arr2` exhaustively. If finds a match, appends indices `list_conflict` with first element being `arr1` position and second `arr2`. Then `fault_index_pos` and `fault_index_neg` are squeezed into unique elements, since an element of `arr1` could be on multiple places of `arr2` and list will have recurrent positions. Finally, matching elements are removed with `np.delete` by taking `fault_index` lists as index to be deleted.

I'm looking for a faster approach for conflict comparison call it `multiprocessing`, `vectorization` or anything else. You could say it won't take much time but actually arrays are in `(x,8,10)` dimensions but I shortened them for sake of clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring the numpy part, finding the conflicting index pairs can be done much faster in pure Python, taking time proportional to `len(a)` plus `len(b)` plus the number of conflicts, rather than the nested loops which take time proportional to the *product* of the vectors' lengths:

```
def conflicts(a, b):
    from collections import defaultdict
    elt2ix = defaultdict(list)
    for i, elt in enumerate(a):
        elt2ix[elt].append(i)
    for j, elt in enumerate(b):
        if elt in elt2ix:
            for i in elt2ix[elt]:
                yield i, j
```

Then, e.g.,

```
for pair in conflicts([1, 2, 4, 5, 2], [2, 3, 8, 4]):
    print(pair)
```

displays

```
(1, 0)
(4, 0)
(2, 3)
```

which are the indices of the matching occurrences of 2 and 4.

Comment: How about creating reverse dictionaries from *both* inputs (maybe call them `elt2ix_a` and `elt2ix_b`) and then do: `for elt in set(elt2ix_a) & set(elt2ix_b): yield from itertools.product(elt2ix_a[elt], elt2ix_b[elt])`

Comment: Would work, takes more memory, haven't timed either. Note that `set(dict1) & set(dict2)` can also be written `dict1.keys() & dict2.keys()`. Haven't timed that either ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could do that with `dict_keys`.

Comment: Python 3's "dict views" act like sets in several respects. Very brief overview here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47273297/python-understanding-dictionary-view-objects

Comment: What if a and b are lists of lists instead of lists of integers? I get unhashable type: list error for `elt2ix[elt].append(i)`

Comment: There are many possible ways to proceed then, but - of course - they're more involved. Too involved to fit in a Stackoverflow comment box. Simplest would be to convert them to tuples. "But what if they're lists of lists _of_ lists?" is the next question then ;-)

Comment: @TimPeters converting list of lists in to a lists of tuples makes this work for me. Thanks for the efforts.

Answer (score 1):

- I would use pandas, which sits on numpy, to create a Boolean mask
- Takes 4 lines of code

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# create test data
np.random.seed(1)
a = np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 1))
np.random.seed(1)
b = np.random.randint(8, 15, size=(10, 1))

# create dataframe
df_a = pd.DataFrame(a)
df_b = pd.DataFrame(b)

# find unique values in df_a
unique_a = df_a[0].unique().tolist()

# create a Boolean mask and return only values of df_b not found in df_a
values_not_in_a = df_b[~df_b[0].isin(unique_a)].to_numpy()
```

### Values

```py
a = array([[5],
           [8],
           [9],
           [5],
           [0],
           [0],
           [1],
           [7],
           [6],
           [9]])

b = array([[13],
           [11],
           [12],
           [ 8],
           [ 9],
           [11],
           [13],
           [ 8],
           [ 8],
           [ 9]])

# final output array
values_not_in_a = array([[13],
                         [11],
                         [12],
                         [11],
                         [13]])
```

### Only using numpy

```py
import numpy

# create test data
np.random.seed(1)
a = np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 1))
np.random.seed(1)
b = np.random.randint(8, 15, size=(10, 1))

ua = np.unique(a)  # unique values of a
ub = np.unique(b)  # unique values of b

mask_b = np.isin(b, ua, invert=True)
mask_a = np.isin(a, ub, invert=True)

b_values_not_in_a = b[mask_b]
a_values_not_in_b = a[mask_a]

# b_values_not_in_a
array([13, 11, 12, 11, 13])

# a_values_not_in_b
array([5, 5, 0, 0, 1, 7, 6])
```

### `timeit`

```py
# using the following arrays
np.random.seed(1)
a = np.random.randint(10, size=(90000, 1))
np.random.seed(1)
b = np.random.randint(8, 15, size=(120000, 1))

%%timeit
5.6 ms ± 151 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: @0x5453 That's true, as I say in the first bullet of my post. However, using pandas, I don't need to transpose the shape of the array to create the mask.

Comment: @colt.exe this changes the scope of the original question. (90000, 80) is 90k rows and 80 columns. Now it's not clear what you're trying accomplish. Are you now trying to remove all the values from a 1d array from each column of the 2d array?

Comment: @colt.exe However, if I understand correctly, If you have a 1d array whose values you want removed from each column of the 2d array, you can do as I've shown, but use a loop to apply the the mask to each column of the 2d array. However, I don't think you can combine them back into an array, because the column lengths must be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Please work through some tutorials on the vector capabilities of NumPy, as well as the sequence inclusion operators of Python.  You are trying to program a large-scale application that sorely needs language facilities you haven't yet learned.

That said, perhaps the fastest way to do this is to convert each to a `set` and take the set intersection.  The involved operations are **O(n)** for a sequence/set of **N** elements; your nested loop is **O(N*M)** (on the two sequence sizes).

Any tutorial on Python sets will walk you through this.

Comment: Well I certainly thought of sets, but had an uneducated guess that there may be more faster ways for achieving this. However I do fully agree that I have to take some tutorials and will definitely to when I have spare time. Appraciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

As @Prune suggested, here's a solution that uses `set`s:

```
overlap = np.array(list(set(arr1) & set(arr2)))  # Depending on array shapes you may need to flatten or slice first
arr1 = arr1[~np.isin(arr1, overlap)]
arr2 = arr2[~np.isin(arr2, overlap)]
```

Comment: I didn't use a mask in this way, because it does work for the shape of the data presented by the OP.

Comment: arrarys are np arrays and after reshaping them to `(-1,80)` overlap throws unhashable type: list.