# Faster nested row comparison with 2D numpy arrays

Tags: python, loops, set

I have two very large arrays `X_pos` and `X_neg` with sizes `(900000,100)` and `(1200000,100)`. I'd like to find out if any row element of `arr1` is present on `arr2`. If there is a match, I need a list of indices for the matching rows. Later I need to remove them and make both arrays having no same row match.  For now, I'm using `for` loops:

```
list_conflict=[]
for i in range (len(X_pos)):
    for j in range (len(X_neg)):
        if (X_pos[i]==X_neg[j]):
            list_conflict.append([i,j])

fault_index_pos = np.unique([x[0] for x in list_conflict])
fault_index_neg = np.unique([x[1] for x in list_conflict])

X_neg = np.delete(X_neg,fault_index_neg,axis=0)
X_pos = np.delete(X_pos,fault_index_pos,axis=0)
```

It takes an element of `X_pos` on outer loop and compares it with every element of `X_neg` exhaustively. If finds a match, appends indices `list_conflict` with first element being `X_pos` position and second `X_pos`. Then `fault_index_pos` and `fault_index_neg` are squeezed into unique elements, since an element of `X_pos` could be on multiple places of `X_pos` and list will have recurrent positions. Finally, matching elements are removed with `np.delete` by taking `fault_index` lists as index to be deleted.

I'm looking for a faster approach for conflict comparison call it `set`, `vectorization` or anything else.

P.S. Example arrays:

X_pos

`array([[0,1,2,3,4],[0,1,2,3,5],[0,1,2,3,6],[2,4,5,6,7]])`

X_neg

`array([[2,4,5,6,7],[0,1,2,3,7],[0,1,2,3,4],[0,1,2,3,9],[1,9,3,2,5]])`

It should return the indices that are duplicate in the other array which is `list_conflict = [[0,1],[3,1]]`. Then by these indices, I should be able to delete same elements in both arrays. Possible duplicate question is what I asked yesterday, but it fails to precisely explain the problem with unnecessary simplification. Those answers are not a solution to this problem and they had to be altered in some way to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Speeding up nested loop comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62883749/speeding-up-nested-loop-comparison)

Comment: @Ehsan lol he asked that question too :)

Comment: @OmerBenHaim I am confused too. Maybe OP can elaborate on how this is different than that and what he is looking on improving upon answers on his previous post.

Comment: i don't think it is different, or maybe not by much since the operations in the answer to the post you mentioned should work here as well.

Comment: Could you please provide sample input, as well as expected output?

Comment: More elaboration added.

Answer (score 0):

Find rows where `a` contains rows of `b`:

```
duplicate_a = np.isin(a, b).all(axis=1)
```

For these rows, find the corresponding rows in b:

```
duplicate_b = np.isin(b, a[duplicate_a, :]).all(axis=1)
```

to get the indices of these duplicates:

```
duplicate_b_rows = b[duplicate_b]

duplicate_b_indices = duplicate_b.nonzero()[0]
duplicate_a_indices = duplicate_a.nonzero()[0]

duplicates = [
    (duplicate_a_indices[i], duplicate_b_indices[np.isin(duplicate_b_rows, row).all(axis=1)])
    for i, row in enumerate(a[duplicate_a, :])
]
```

For example,

```
a = np.random.random((1000, 100))
b = np.random.random((500, 100))
b[1, :] = a[3, :]
b[5, :] = a[3, :]
b[2, :] = a[1, :]
```

Would output

```
[(1, array([2])), (3, array([1, 5]))]
```

indicating that a[1, :] corresponds to b[2, :], and a[3, :] corresponds to b[1, :] as well as b[5, :].

To flatten this completely:

```
duplicates = [
    (duplicate_a_indices[i], duplicate_b_indices[j])
    for i, row in enumerate(a[duplicate_a, :]) for j in np.isin(duplicate_b_rows, row).all(axis=1).nonzero()[0]
]
```

It'd now output `[(1, 2), (3, 1), (3, 5)]` for the above example

But a faster way would be to use a lookup table for the rows:

```
a_lookup = {row.tostring(): i for i, row in enumerate(a)}

duplicates = [(a_lookup[row.tostring()], i) for i, row in enumerate(b) if row.tostring() in a_lookup]
```

This runs much faster than the numpy version in case you have many rows, as the complexity is `O(N*K + M*K))` where `N` and `M` are the number of rows in a and b respectively, and `K` is the number of elements per row.

While the complexity of the numpy solution is `O(M*N*K)`.

Note that this would work fine to find exact duplicates, but if your data is composed of floating point numbers, you may miss "duplicates" which are essentially the same, but due to the limited resolution of the float would differ in a digit or more.