# Which datatype should I choose for a units selection in an RTS game?

Tags: python, types, protocol-buffers, abstract-data-type

What is a good data type for a unit collection in an rts?
Im contributing to [an api that lets you write bots for the strategy game Starcraft2 in Python](https://github.com/Dentosal/python-sc2).

Right now [there is a class `units`](https://github.com/Dentosal/python-sc2/blob/master/sc2/units.py) that inherits from `list`. Every frame, a new `units` object gets created and then selections of these units are made, creating new `units` objects, for example with a filter for all enemy units or all flying units.

We use these selections to find the closest enemy to control our units, select our units that can attack right now or need a different order and so on.

But this also means we do a lot of filtering by attributes of each unit in every frame which takes a lot of time. The time for inititalizing one `units` object alone is 2e-5 to 5e-5 sec and we do it millions of times per game which can slow down the bot and tests a lot, in addition to the filtering process with loops over each unit in the `units` object.

Is there a better datataype for this?
Maybe something that does not need to be recreated every time for each selection in one frame, but just starts with the initial list of all units we get from the protocol buffer and then the selections and filters can be applied without recreating the object? What would be a good way to implement this so that filtering multiple times per frame is not that slow and/or complicated?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like a ADT problem at all. This sounds like inefficient programming. It is impossible for us to tell you the correct message to construct to achieve what you're going for.

What you should probably be investigating is how to construct a `UnitView` if you don't actually need to modify the `unit`s data. Consider something similar to how dictionaries return `views` in Python 3. [See here for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957750/what-are-dictionary-view-objects).