# Why numpy.argmax() cannot give correct answer to dict.values() in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, dictionary

**Data**:

```py
import numpy as np

d = {"a": 10, "b": 11, "c":12}
print(d)  # This gives {'a': 10, 'b': 11, 'c': 12}
```

**Problem**:
So we try to obtain the index of the max value in the `d.values()`:

```py
print(np.argmax(d.values()))
```

This gives 0, which is **incorrect**. The correct answer should be 2.
But if we try this:

```py
print(d.values())  # This gives dict_values([10, 11, 12])
print(np.argmax([10, 11, 12]))
```

This is correct

So why is this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should look at the result of `np.array(d.values())` it does not do what you think it does. You might try: `print(np.argmax(list(d.values())))` instead.

Comment: in general, you should avoid using `np.*` functions with non-numpy data structures aside from maybe lists of numbers. But even then, you really should convert to a numpy array explicitly and understand what you are creating

Comment: If you do print type(d.values()) you'll see that it is a class of dictionary values.
The d.values() returns a dictionary view object and not a list/array whereas np.argmax expects an array/list as its input.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects

Also, the print() function is sophisticated enough to handle several types and show the values nicely formatted.

Comment: I agree with OP that this is very confusing. The documentation says that one of the possible conditions for `np.array` to do what you expect it to is that the argument be a sequence.  And even though `d.values()` feels a lot like a sequence in that it is a sequence of elements with a definite order (of of 3.7?), you can't actually use indexing on it, so it isn't.

Comment: @FrankHan was your doubt cleared?

Comment: @Goku Yes. Thank you very much!

Comment: you're welcome !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Dictionary view objects are different from Lists.

> Views are "pseudo-set-like", in that they don't support indexing, so what you can do with them is test for membership and iterate over them (because keys are hashable and unique, the keys and items views are more "set-like" in that they don't contain duplicates).

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957750/what-are-dictionary-view-objects#:~:text=Just%20from%20reading,are%20still%20preferable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957750/what-are-dictionary-view-objects#:%7E:text=Just%20from%20reading,are%20still%20preferable).

```
import numpy as np

d = {"a": 10, "b": 11, "c":12}
view_object = d.values()
```

Now if you try to index `view_object`:

```
print(view_object[0])

TypeError: 'dict_values' object is not subscriptable
```

**Unlike lists, you cannot index Dictionary view objects**

---

Coming back to `np.argmax()`:

> Returns the indices of the maximum values along an axis.

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.26.0/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L1140-L1229

**If the object is not subscriptable, np.argmax() will return 0**.

e.g.

```
np.argmax({1,2,3})
0

np.argmax(d.values())
0
```